# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JQuery UI Maps plugin? Works locally, not on the server

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm working on a fairly simple site using Twitter Bootstrap. I'm having an issue with getting my Google Maps plugin to work. On localhost using Apache, it works fine. On the server, also Apache, it does not. I get this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

On the first line of this file (jquery.ui.map.min.js):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html><head>
<title>Menu for /assets/js/jquery.ui.map.min.js</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Menu for /assets/js/jquery.ui.map.min.js</h1>
<hr />

<pre>          <a href="http://jhfc-law.com/assets/js/jquery-ui-map">jquery-ui-map</a></pre>
<pre>          <a href="http://jhfc-law.com/assets/js/d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1;};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new">d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1;};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new</a></pre>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to see the problem:

http://jhfc-law.com/contact.html

Again, the map and everything work fine locally. I'm sure the server is reading that DOCTYPE line as an issue due to the opening <, but I'm unsure how to fix this. It's causing this error as well (since the first file is breaking, gmap isn't being initialized so I can't use this following line):

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'gmap'`

Which is in this method in my scripts.js file (which is being loaded after the previous file):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(31.22633, -85.39422);
    $('.map').gmap({'center': position,'zoom': 15, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'gmap'
            var self = this;
            self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map javascript isn't on the server. This is what you're linking to: http://jhfc-law.com/assets/js/jquery.ui.map.min.js

Furthermore, it looks like the correct (?) link is broken as well: http://jhfc-law.com/assets/js/jquery-ui-map

Comment: Hmm, the jquery.ui.map.min.js that is showing up when I click the first link you posted is the exact file that I have on my local box that works fine... Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I don't know what your setup is but I'm getting a page that says "Menu for /assets/js/jquery.ui.map.min.js" http://cl.ly/image/193J3I0y2509. It seems like your page that's referencing the js is having the same issue since it's returning a html document instead of javascript.

Comment: Ya that's what I'm seeing too, but forcing the mime-type in the <script> tag that loads that file doesn't fix the issue.. so weird.

Comment: If that's the case, you're not having a problem with the plugin, you're having an issue with your server and possibly apache control directives.

Comment: I'm actually contacting my server administrator right now. Thanks a ton!